# Properties of $T \circ S$ where $S: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^4$ and $T: \mathbb R^4 \to \mathbb R^3$ are linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^4$ and $T: \mathbb R^4 \to \mathbb R^3$ be linear transformation such that $T\circ S$ is the identity map of $\mathbb R^3$. Then

1. $S\circ  T$ is the identity map of $\mathbb R^4$.
2. $S \circ  T$ is one-one, but not onto.
3. $S \circ T$ is not one-one,but onto.
4. $S \circ T$ is neither one-one nor onto.

Since $T\circ S$ is the identity map of $\mathbb R^3$ then it must be one-one and the dimension of domain ($\mathbb R^3$) and co-domain ($\mathbb R^3$) are same then it is a bijective map. Then we also say that $(T\circ S)^{-1}$ also exist. Then how to show which one is correct from the above options.

Answer (score 3):

Since $T\circ S$ is the identity map (so bijective) then it's a classic result that $T$ is onto and $S$ is one to one. Hence by the rank nullity theorem $\dim\ker T=1$ and $\dim{\rm im}S=3$ and then $S\circ T$ is neither one to one nor onto.

**Added** We can see the result using contradiction. If one of the options $1,2$ or $3$ holds then $T$ or $S$ or both become bijective which's a contradiction since $\Bbb R^3$ isn't isomorphic to $\Bbb R^4$.

Comment: Would you mind expanding the "classic result"? It's not obvious to me.

Comment: See the classic result [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/539786/if-g-circ-f-is-injective-what-can-you-say-about-injectivity-of-f-and-g) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/750535/show-that-if-f-circ-g-is-surjective-then-f-is-surjective-and-g-the-fun)@sidht